# How is OpenSSL related to OpenSSH?

Tags: tls, ssh

Is OpenSSH using OpenSSL to encrypt traffic? Or something else?

Comment: This is not strictly a duplicate, however this earlier question is probably relevant to help explain the concepts. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-is-the-difference-between-ssl-vs-ssh-which-is-more-secure

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OpenSSH is a **program** depending on OpenSSL the **library**, specifically OpenSSH uses the `libcrypto` part of OpenSSL.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that OpenSSH does not use the TLS protocol thats used for HTTPS etc. OpenSSH uses some of the OpenSSL cryptographic primatives.

Answer (score 6):

**OpenSSH can be compiled without OpenSSL since 2014**:

- http://it.slashdot.org/story/14/04/30/1822209/openssh-no-longer-has-to-depend-on-openssl
- http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&m=139879453001957&w=2

The author stated that this was in the making for a long time, but Heartbleed was likely the last straw.